# Keep EditText from expanding horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the EditTexts to expand vertically (I have textMultiline on there to allow this), but once the text overflows into multiline, it makes the horizontal width extend a bit too.

Is there a way to force the width to stay static, while still being the full width of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution accidentally: By putting the button in a tablerow (like everything else that was in the layout), it was forced to change like everything else. By just allowing the button to sit below the previous rows (but still within the table), it stretched itself appropriately without going too far.